# Quasar2 Vue3 QSelect end of the multiple selection trigger when it loses focus

Tags: drop-down-menu, vuejs3, html-select, quasar-framework, dropdownbox

I have the following template:

```
<template>
  <q-item tag="label" v-ripple>
    <q-select
      borderless
      stack-label
      emit-value
      map-options
      multiple
      class="full-width"
      v-model="model"
      :options="options"
      :label="name"
      @change="onValueChange"
    />
  </q-item>
</template>
```

Since it is a multiple selection, I would like to be able to know when the selections complete which is usually when the `QSelect` loses focus or closed. This is so that I don't trigger any unnecessary action for every single change during the multi-selection by the user. The `@change` is not triggered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slot:

```
<template>
  <q-item tag="label" v-ripple>
    <q-select
      borderless
      stack-label
      emit-value
      map-options
      multiple
      class="full-width"
      v-model="model"
      :options="options"
      :label="name"
    >
      <template v-slot:after>
        <q-btn
          data-test="btnMultipleDropDownSetting"
          round
          dense
          flat
          color="primary"
          icon="done"
          @click="multiSelectionCompletes"
          :disable="submitButtonDisable"
        />
      </template>
    </q-select>
  </q-item>
</template>
```